# How do I make check box press the CTRL key forever when ticked?

Tags: vb.net

So I am a new coder and I am trying to make a autosprint for Minecraft which the default key is CTRL and I am trying to make my checkbox hold the CTRL key down forever when the box is ticked but when you untick it it releases the key, does anyone have any code for that in VB.NET I am really stuck.

I have tried the code SendKeys.Send but that hasn't worked out for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB Press and hold keystroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382704/vb-press-and-hold-keystroke) - with the option to repeat the keypress every _x_ milliseconds, if wanted.

Comment: _"pressing forever"_ in computer terms means sending a "key down" event but never a "key up". This can be accomplished using my code above in the linked duplicate. To hold it "forever", specify a wait interval of 2147483647. That'll wait for approximately 25 days before releasing the key again, and I don't think the user will be playing consecutively for that long. :)